# Not getting the expected results - javascript

Tags: javascript

I am following this example from a book but I am not getting the same results shown in the book.

Two HTML page.

*calcfactorialtopframe.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function calcFactorial(factorialNumber) {

        var factorialResult = 1;

        for (; factorialNumber > 0; factorialNumber--) {
            factorialResult = factorialResult * factorialNumber;
        }

        return factorialResult;

    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<frameset cols="100%,*">
    <frame name="fraCalcFactorial" src="calcfactorial.html"></frame>
</frameset>

</body>
</html>
```

*calcfactorial.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function butCalculate_onclick() {
            try {

                if (window.top.calcFactorial == null) {
                    throw "This page is not loaded within the correct frameset";
                };

                if (document.form1.txtNum1.value == "") {
                    throw "!Please enter a value before you calculate its factorial";
                };

                if (isNaN(document.form1.txtNum1.value)) {
                    throw "!Please enter a valid number";
                };

                if (document.form1.txtNum1.value < 0) {
                    throw "!Please enter a positive number";
                };

                document.form1.txtResult.value = window.parent.calcFactorial(document.form1.txtNum1.value);
            }
            catch (exception) {
                if (typeof(exception) == "string") {

                    if (exception.charAt(0) == "!") {

                        alert(exception.substr(1));
                        document.form1.txtNum1.focus();
                        document.form1.txtNum1.select();

                    } else {
                        alert(exception);
                    }

                } else {
                    alert("The following error occurred " + exception.message);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" name="form1">

        <input type="text" name="txtNum1" size="3" /> factorial is
        <input type="text" name="txtResult" size="25" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Calculate Factorial" name="butCalculate" onclick="butCalculate_onclick()" />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting the error "This page is not loaded within the correct frameset".

The purpose of this exercise in the book is to show how try catch throw works.

Thanks

Comment: Thats quite a complicated way to explain how `try...catch` works! The reason you are getting this result is because `window.top.calcFactorial` _is_ `null`, so an exception is `throw`n in your `try` statement, outputting (or _referring_) it to the `catch`. I actually don't think that iFrames can access their parents' javascript function, so it would obviously be `null`. For a good explanation of `try...catch`, check out MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: Your try catch is working as the 'if (window.top.calcFactorial == null)' is throwig the error

Comment: I'll have a read of the link provided. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my comment is still very relevant, but I did find the problem: you are actually not referring to the parent, for that you need an `iframe`. Change the following code:

```
<frameset cols="100%,*">
    <frame name="fraCalcFactorial" src="calcfactorial.html"></frame>
</frameset>
```

to this:

```
<iframe name="fraCalcFactorial" src="calcfactorial.html"></iframe>
```

Now `window.top` is accessible to the child frame! I'll be honest, I'm not sure *why* this is as my knowledge of framesets is very limited and I forgot how to access them years ago.

But seriously, this does not sound like a good book if it teaches you to do things using a `<frameset>`... I haven't seen those in almost 20 years! Your best friend and resource is the `Mozilla Developer Network`. I find their code is really well explained and it contains a huge swath of modern, up-to-date web!

Comment: Thanks. That resolved the issue. Yes, I agree that this book seems to be using old methods of doing things.